# How to deploy WCF service application on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF services.I have made a service application and put the application code directory under default website of IIS.It connects with my client very well.

I want to know how to deploy my service on IIS as binary,as of now my whole source code is visible on server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it is called WCF Service Publishing

check the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924407.aspx)

after publishing you have only **assembly files, Web.config file, and .svc** file in the server

Answer (score 6):

1 : Publish your wcf service application from VS and give a publish path.

2 : Create a virtual directory in IIS which will point to the publish directory

3 : Set the virtual directory default page to .SVC file of your application.

Then try to browse it ..I hope you will be able to make it now..

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c0a54e7-af4b-422f-bf5d-5f2f93d46ed0/deploying-wcf-service-to-iis-75

1. You need to create a new application on IIS for your WCF application.
2. To configure the service using a specific port as `nettcp` endpoint port on IIS, you need to edit "Bindings..." section on "Default Web Site", change the "net.tcp" type binding to use your desired port, (for example, to use 22550, set Binding information to "22550:*")
3. You can just set `nettcp` endpoint address with relative URI. IIS will transform the address to an absolute URL automatically.
   #iv-v), To enable `nettcp` protocol on the IIS application, you could open "Advanced Settings" on a specific IIS application, edit "Enabled Protocols" pair, add "net.tcp".
4. Yes, add a MEX endpoint, and add `serviceMetadata` to `ServiceBehavior`. See this configuration sample:

```xml
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="nettcp_wcf.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="nettcp_wcf.Service1Behavior">
        <!--use relative url-->
        <endpoint address="nettcp" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="nettcp_wcf.IService1">
        </endpoint>
        <!--add mex endpoint-->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="nettcp_wcf.Service1Behavior">
          <!--enable metadata service-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is an article about configuring IIS to host `nettcp WCF`, please have a look:
http://blogs.msdn.com/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/08/iis-7-support-for-non-http-protocols.aspx